# How to get OpenLayers to select a country from a country code?

Tags: openlayers

I have a program which uses OpenLayers and basically, a user types in a three digit country code and then I want that country to be selected on the map. So if a user typed "USA", then the United States would be selected on the map. I'm very new to using OpenLayers but I think I need to use ol.interaction.Select to do this.

Comment: You need country code and country boundary coordinates to draw polygons to show it's selected.

Comment: Source for boundary, name and code: https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/blob/master/countries.geo.json?short_path=afdfc39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you need:

1. A vector data source corresponding to countries, and indexed by their three-digit country code.  [dube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304179/dube)'s answer above points to one, and OpenLayers appears to have the same file on their site [here](https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson).  Conveniently, these files use the country code as the feature Id, and it's trivial to look up a feature by Id in a vector data source.
2. An OpenLayers map with at least a vector layer containing the above source.
3. Optionally a base layer for the map containing image tiles.  You can alternatively do without this layer if you use the vector data source to draw the country boundaries, using a map layer whose source is the country vectors, with an appropriate fill and outline style.  However, the country vector data is pretty coarse, and map tiles (OpenStreetMap, Stamen, Bing, Google, etc) might look prettier, especially if a user zooms in much at all.
4. An overlay layer for highlighting.  This would be a vector layer with a highlighting fill and outline style (e.g., red or bold, maybe with some non-transparent fill color), to which you add and remove the selected country's feature object when the user types a recognizable country code.

The OpenLayers [vector-layer](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html) example contains 90% of the code you need.  Instead of watching mouse movements, you watch for changes of a text element into which the user types the country codes.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ejschoen/5e37eb7a597ad7f76c1578efb803d7b1) for an example.